# Is binding to a TypeLiteral a good or bad practice in google guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Google guice uses `new TypeLiteral<C<T>>() {}` to overcome the fact that we cannot use `C<T>.class`.

Now it is common to the following:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<C<T>>() {}).to(MyCSubclassTypedToT.class);
```

Imagine a different scenario however. We have a generic interface, that we want to inject and the implementation we have is be provided by a generic class.

Guice allows you to do this like this:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<MyGenericInterface<T>>() {}).to(new TypeLiteral<MyGenericClass<T>>() {});
```

Another way of doing this would be to extend MyGenericClass like this:

```
MyTypedClass extends MyGenericClass<T>
```

and then bind it like this:

```
bind(MyGenericInterface<T>>() {}).to(MyTypedClass.class);
```

If MyGenericInterface is injected a lot (albeit with different types), and every time I do inject it I use MyGenericClass, the latter approach leads to overly verbose code. Hence I'm leaning towards using the former.

I would be very keen to hear other peoples opinion about the use of a TypeLiteral in the to clause of a guice binding. I'm afraid that I might a bit to short sited and thus don't see the pitfalls of this approach.

Comment: I cannot quite understand how generic class can provide implementation of non-generic interface "when appropriately typed". Does is compile? Can you show an example?

Comment: perhaps I oversimplified the example. I'll update it.

Comment: @axtavt I hope the question is clearer now.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. For the 2nd and 3rd examples, do you mean to have `bind(new TypeLiteral<MyGenericInterface<T>>(){})...` instead of `bind(MyGenericInterface<T>.class)...`? As you said at the top of your question, it doesn't make sense to do `C<T>.class`. Then, is your question just "Should I bind to the generic class? vs. should I bind to non-generic typed classes?"

Comment: @AndrewMcNamee you are right, I made a mistake. My question is as you've guessed "Should I bind to the generic class? vs. should I bind to non-generic typed classes?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, using a `TypeLiteral` for the generic implementation strikes me as being much better.

Let me phrase it this way: "Would the subclass `MyTypedClass` exist if you weren't using Guice?". An essential guideline of Guice is: you shouldn't have to alter your implementation classes to fit the DI framework (well, with the exception of things like the `@Inject` annotation).

And what do you gain from subclassing the concrete-yet-generic class? One big loss is that you have to duplicate MyGenericClass's constructor in all the subclasses. All in all, it seems like extra code without much gain.

All-in-all, there's generally nothing wrong with using a `TypeLiteral`. And if it's in the `.to(...)` portion of the binding clause (as opposed to `bind(...)`, it won't even affect the publicly-visible portion of your `Module`'s bindings, so I don't think there's much to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

There are usually two scenarios:

1. You want to bind all implementation of `MyGenericInterface` to `MyGenericClass`
2. You want to bind implementation of `MyGenericInterface` base on its type

For the first scenario, `bind(MyGenericInterface).to(MyGenericClass);` will be enough, simper and easier to understand.

For the 2nd scenario, you will need to bind implementation of a specific class to a specific implementation, which TypeLiteral will come into play.

Furthermore, the code in your question is not clear that whether `T` is a actual class, or a generic type. If it's a generic type,

`bind(new TypeLiteral<MyGenericInterface<T>>() {}).to(new TypeLiteral<MyGenericClass<T>>() {});`

and

`MyTypedClass extends MyGenericClass<T>`

won't compile, as some actual class is not provided.

Comment: The question is more about good practice. Your example deals with the case where bind() argument is generic. My question was more about the case when to() argument is generic.